# OneDrive Push Notifications

Tags: webhooks, onedrive

I'm just getting started with the OneDrive API. I have an application that integrates with Google Drive and Dropbox and receives push notifications from these services, and I'm looking to include OneDrive support.

Maybe I'm not looking in the [right place](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243643.aspx), but I can't find documentation on how/if I can receive push notifications for changes on a users OneDrive account. Or, even a list of changes to a service - like Dropbox's [delta](https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-python-sdk-1.6-docs/index.html?highlight=delta#dropbox.client.DropboxClient.delta) call, or Google's [changes list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/changes/list) call.

Ideally, I'm wondering if OneDrive supports something similar to Google Drive's [watch changes](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/changes/watch) function, or Dropbox's [webhooks](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/90/announcing-dropbox-webhooks) or [longpoll_delta](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#longpoll-delta). Anyone able to shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, that is not supported by the current version of the OneDrive API.

Comment: Hi there @Jeanine, is this still so? I need to figure out which API to use between OneDrive, Google Drive and Dropbox, and I need to get a list of folder & file metadata of a user's entire directory. So will I not be able to do this (as well as not being able to "poll" for changes to simulate a sync? Thanks!

Comment: There have been no changes/updates to the OneDrive API offering at this point, unfortunately.

Comment: Hi @JeanineMS, is there a plan to include webhooks anytime soon? It's a dealbreaker for something I'm working on. Thanks!

Comment: @Lombo Thanks for the feedback! Both the ability to find changes and to receive notifications when files change are pretty high on our backlog. We're working through a couple of other key changes first, but we'll get there.

Comment: @RGregg is this still the situation? if so, can we be done by periodically looking on all folder files and comparing to previous details (date, time, size etc)?

Comment: @Lior We're getting very close to having a service-to-service story for push notifications. More details will be available on dev.onedrive.com towards the end of the June. We already have a sync protocol through our [view.changes](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/view_changes.htm) action.

Comment: Sorry to keep nagging you on this one but... Any news yet?

Answer (score 3):

Try **view.delta**: https://dev.onedrive.com/items/view_delta.htm

```
GET /drive/items/{item-id}/view.delta
GET /drive/root:/{item-path}:/view.delta
```

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft is introducing Webhooks
https://dev.onedrive.com/misc/webhooks.htm